# Handle Click Event on Item in a ComboBox

Tags: winforms, combobox

Does anyone know of any event or sequence of events to be able to handle when a user clicks an item in a ComboBox?  Currently the only events that I see being fire from ComboBox within WinForms is SelectedIndexChanged or SelectedValueChanged.  The problem with these events is that they are also fired under many other scenerios such as when the user presses up or down arrow (even if the ComboBox is not open).

```
ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += (o, e) => Console.WriteLine("ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged");
ComboBox.SelectedValueChanged += (o, e) => Console.WriteLine("ComboBox_SelectedValueChanged");
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: The SelectedIndex value really *did* change.  This ought not be a problem.  Subclassing the dropdown window is very ugly code to get right but is technically possible with the NativeWindow class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are asking about when the user clicks an item in the ComboBox to select it, you can use the [ComboBox.SelectionChangeCommitted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectionchangecommitted.aspx) event.

Comment: This helped, along with checking to see if the combobox is dropped down.  The only time the this event fires when the ComboBox is dropped down is when the user clicks it or hits enter.


            var comboBox = (ComboBox) sender;
            if (comboBox.DroppedDown) DoSomething(comboBox.SelectedItem);